# How to type apostrophes in verbatim material

Tags: punctuation, verbatim

How can I type an apostrophe in `\verb` mode? I've tried using `\'` and I've seen solutions that work in the verbatim environment, but I'm not sure how to do this inline. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  Using \verb|\verb|: \verb|'| \verb|"| \verb|`|

  Using \verb|\texttt|: \texttt{'} \texttt{"} \texttt{`}
\end{document}
```

[image]